# How can I set the current price to a variable?

Tags: template, php-5.4

I need to use the price variable from price.phtml in a different phtml file. I have tried including price.phtml with output buffering so the echos don't display. But I was never able to print any of the variables successfully. So I do not know what I am doing wrong or if accessing the price.phtml variables is even possible.

Any ideas? Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can do this by magento registry

Add below code `Mage::register('some_name', $var);` in price.html and then get  this value in other phtml

```
$my_var = Mage::registry('some_name');
```

then unset this some_name variable use below code

```
Mage::unregister('some_name');
```